# Swift: Cannot convert value of type '(Any) throws -> Bool? to expected argument type '(Any) throws -> Bool?

Tags: arrays, swift

I'm trying to take two arrays and combine them into a new array without any duplicates. I can't get around the following error, however.

```
Cannot convert value of type '(Any) throws -> Bool? to expected argument type '(Any) throws -> Bool?
```

I'm trying to combine two arrays which contain multiple dictionaries. I'm comparing the "name" in each dictionary in the array.

```
let array2Name = array2.flatMap({$0["name"]}) // ["eli", "will"]
array2 = array1.reduce(array2) { !array2Name.contains(where: $1["name"] as! (Any) throws -> Bool? ?? "") ? $0 + [$1] : $0 }
print(array2)
```

Comment: You are simply confusing the compiler here. Have you tried `contains(element: $1["name"] ?? "")` instead of `contains(where:...)`?

Comment: With this change, it returns the same error recommending element be changed to where, which leads me down the path where I get the same errors as previously

Answer (score 1):

You aren't properly comparing the value that is passed into the contains closure. And you can't use the `$` variable inside a closure within the closure.

```
let array2Name = array2.flatMap { $0["name"] }
array2 = array1.reduce(array2, { result, value in
    !array2Name.contains(where: { $0 == value["name"] ?? "" }) ? result + [value]: result
})
print(array2)
```

---

Edit:
This does away with the `array2Name` value.

```
array2 = array1.reduce(array2) { result, value in
    result.contains(where: { $0["name"] == value["name"] }) ? result: result + [value]
}
```